# How does developing an OpenGL ES application for the Raspberry Pi differ from desktop Linux?

Tags: opengles

I am beginning to learn OpenGL ES 2.0 through both the excellent book [*OpenGL ES 2.0 Programming Guide*](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9780321563835) and the famous [Arc Synthesis OpenGL tutorial](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9780321563835).  However, I have heard that the Raspberry Pi's OpenGL development process is a bit...*different* than that of desktop Linux.  Indeed, I tried running an unmodified OpenGL ES program on the Pi and it was *really slow*.

Additionally, I took a look at some of the [example programs for the Raspberry Pi](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/tree/master/opt/vc/src/hello_pi), but they were all either too complicated or didn't deal with OpenGL ES, and I was not able to gain any knowledge.  I am, after all, a beginner at this.  So, what's the difference?  What modifications do my OpenGL ES programs need to run on the Pi?  And what's with the `bcm_host_init()` and `memset(state, 0, sizeof(*state))` functions?

Answer (score 1):

Pi can run GL in two ways -- the traditional GL-on-X11 way which uses the glx() calls and also directly, without starting X11.. which is where the bcm_host_init()
calls come in -- they're the chipset driver API (bcm => Broadcom)

Comment: Could you expand on this answer a bit more?  Right now it is more of a comment in my opinion.  I will upvote it when you do.